# How to Upgrade to log4j 2.x without changing any import statements

Tags: log4j, upgrade, log4j2, executable-jar

What is the best way to upgrade from log4j 1.x to 2.x
I have an ANT project. I just deleted the old jar and replaced it with the new log4j is that enough ?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 2 does not use the same configuration file format. However, Log4j 2.13.0 introduced experimental support for some Log4j 1 configuration files. So you have two choices:

1. Follow the steps outlined at [Migrating from Log4j 1.x](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) which involves including the log4j-1.2-api jar and converting your configuration files to Log4j 2 format or
2. Include the log4j-1.2-api jar but instead of converting your configuration files follow the steps at [Log4j 2 Compatibility with Log4j 1](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/compatibility.html)

Note that since option 2 is experimental you may have configurations that Log4j 2 cannot handle. If that happens the Log4j 2 team welcomes you to report a Jira issue to determine how the support can be improved.

Comment: Thank you @rgoers. I will try doing that.